# Modifie generated Navigation Drawer from Android Studio

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, generated

I generated the Navigation Drawer Activity from Android Studio.

Now I see 3 text items in the drawer, how do I add more text items?

This is the adapter:

```
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            new String[]{
                    getString(R.string.title_section1),
                    getString(R.string.title_section2),
                    getString(R.string.title_section3),
            }));
```

I tried to add a String into the String array, but the navigation drawer still shows only 3 items.

Comment: If you want us to help you, you have to post the entire code, only a piece of it is not enough

Answer (score 0):

After adding any data to adapter you are supposed to call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

You will have to hold reference on adapter instead of using anonymous class.
Calling notifyDataSetChanged will redraw listview so your goal will be achieved.